# Cannot call the method of class

Tags: c#, class, nullreferenceexception

Namespace are same of both the class. I need to call xyz() method in WhatsAppSend Class.

This is my method in Form1.cs

```
public void SendWhatsAppMsg()
{
try
{
 WhatsAppSend ws;
 ws = new WhatsAppSend(this); //Error Coming on this
ws.xyz(txtNickName.Text.ToString(),
       gridSender.Rows[iCurrentChannelNo].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
       gridSender.Rows[iCurrentChannelNo].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
       CreateArrayFrom(i + 1, (i + 1) + iMsgLimitPerNo),
       dropWhatsappType.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
       SendingData(dropWhatsappType.SelectedItem.ToString()), 
       ext);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
txt.log += e.ToString();
}
}
```

Method Which I am trying to call in another class WhatsAppSend.cs

```
namespace WhatsApp_Bulk
{
    public class WhatsAppSend 
    {
        public static WhatsAppBulk form1;
        public WhatsAppSend(WhatsAppBulk _form1)
          {
              form1 = _form1;
          }
    public static String line = "";
    public static String command = "";
    public static string[] dst;
    public static int count_sleep = Convert.ToInt32(form1.txtMsgGap.Text);
    public static string WhatsAppType = "";
    public static string DataToSend = "";
    public static string ext = "";
 public void xyz(string nickname, string sender, string password, string[] Datadst, string DataWhatsAppType, string DataDataToSend, string Dataext)
        {
            dst = Datadst;
            WhatsAppType = DataWhatsAppType;
            DataToSend = DataDataToSend;
            ext = Dataext;
            WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(sender, password, nickname, true);
         }
     }
}
```

Error :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WhatsApp_Bulk.WhatsAppSend' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at WhatsApp_Bulk.WhatsAppSend..cctor() in d:\WhatsApp Bulk\WhatsApp Bulk\WhatsAppSend.cs:line 32
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at WhatsApp_Bulk.WhatsAppSend..ctor(WhatsAppBulk _form1)
   at WhatsApp_Bulk.WhatsAppBulk.SendWhatsAppMsg() in d:\WhatsApp Bulk\WhatsApp Bulk\Form1.cs:line 367
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: in which line the exception is being raised

Comment: Your design is terribly flawed. You're setting `WhatsAppBulk` form instance to static field (`form1`) from a instance constructor. Think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int count_sleep = Convert.ToInt32(form1.txtMsgGap.Text);
```

This line executes on type initialization, when `form1` is `null`.
You set `form1` in the instance constructor, which is executed later.

That is the common reason for `TypeInitializationException`.

**UPD:**

I can suggest the following

```
public class WhatsAppSend
{
    public WhatsAppBulk form1;
    public WhatsAppSend(WhatsAppBulk _form1)
    {
        form1 = _form1;
        count_sleep = Convert.ToInt32(form1.txtMsgGap.Text);
    }
    public String line = "";
    public String command = "";
    public string[] dst;
    public int count_sleep;
    public string WhatsAppType = "";
    public string DataToSend = "";
    public string ext = "";
    public void xyz(string nickname, string sender, string password, string[] Datadst, string DataWhatsAppType, string DataDataToSend, string Dataext)
    {
        dst = Datadst;
        WhatsAppType = DataWhatsAppType;
        DataToSend = DataDataToSend;
        ext = Dataext;
        WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(sender, password, nickname, true);
    }
}
```

Please note that public instance fields are still bad design, but i dont know in which context you will use this class, so i leave them public.

Comment: Also, note that the stack trace told you exactly where the problem was: "at WhatsApp_Bulk.WhatsAppSend..cctor() in d:\WhatsApp Bulk\WhatsApp Bulk\WhatsAppSend.cs:line 32" I.e. line 32 of the .cs file, which should turn out to be that line of code.

Comment: SO what can be done to use `public static int count_sleep = Convert.ToInt32(form1.txtMsgGap.Text);` where I should initialize it

Comment: I believe you must declare `count_sleep` as a non-static field and initialize it in the instance constructor, where `form1` is actually accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Make WhatsAppSend Class Static one and then call, As per my assumption variables declared in that class are the static ones so the class should be having the same Access Modifier.